# Informatica, Multiple emails sent through one session

Tags: email, mapping, workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am currently working on creating an Informatica mapping and workflow where I will have to send emails based on when a specific field in the mapping changes. Right now, I have that field sorted and then sent to a transaction control transformation where I have implemented logic so that if the current field value doesn't match the previous field value, I will then Commit otherwise I will continue the transaction.

The problem I am running into is that at the session level, I will have to send an email out each time the target values are committed (when the field value changes) and I am not entirely sure how to do that. How can I create a workflow where an email will be sent out multiple times within the session? Another important factor is that each time this session is run, the number of emails that have to be sent out could change or the number of rows that are committed each time could also change. So is there a way to implement this logic based on changing criteria?

To give a more concrete example, imagine I have the fields 'Names' and 'Number', where every time the name changes, I have to be able to send an email out to someone listing the 'Names' and the 'Number' fields.

```
Names        Number
Bob          23
Bob          31
Bob          41
Alex         14
Alex         75
Steve        32
Steve        29
Steve        83
```

The next time the session is run though, the fields could be completely different, as shown below, but I would still need the same logic to apply where I have to send an email out to someone if the name changes.

```
Names        Number
Tom          42
Carl         12
Carl         23
Carl         56
Carl         23
Evan         31
Evan         24
Kevin        21
```

Hopefully, what I have said is clear enough. And thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to send multiple emails just via Email Task or session's On Success Email. Those send just one message.

What you could try is to use the output and a shell script that will generate and send the emails for you, using the list as input.